# Cosmos C# IL2CPU Error While invoking?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, cosmos

I've been coding a OS with cosmos in c#. It's 350 lines long. I've just got an error saying "Error Occurred while invoking IL2CPU"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why, you need to remove

```
console.beep();
```

console.beep isn't part of the userkit installation. Only in the Devkit installation.